# The type or namespace name could not be found is shown

Tags: c#, .net

I have created sample application as layers. 
I have a layer which is under `DataAccess` namespace

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using DataAccess.DataAccessLayer; //This line is showing error

namespace AdapterClass
{    
     public class SchemaAdapter
     {    
     }
}
```

Inside a file, intellisense of current namespace only available.
For ex:
In above example, intellisense of `AdapterClass` only available.

Comment: Did you include the appropriate assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your terms. A namespace is different than an assembly. If your data access class (and namespace) is in another project (say class library) then  it is in a different assembly that needs to be referenced. To do that, you can:

Right click the project you shown the code above and right click References => Add Reference => Solution Tab => Click that project